# Dataflow fixed windows at top of the hour

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Is there a way that I can set my Dataflow streaming job's windows to start and end at the top of each hour? I'm currently using 1 hour fixed windows but they appear to start when the job starts, and go in 1 hour increments from there. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed windows represent windows of a specific length (Duration). Windows that start at the top of every hour may have a variable length depending on the hour (eg., leap seconds, etc.)

Calendar Windows provides calendar day, month, etc. windows.

For your use case, you can write your own WindowFn that assigns elements based on their timestamp to a window that starts on the hour and extends until the end of the hour.

Such a WindowFn could be a useful contribution to the Apache Beam SDK. Consider filing an issue and contributing the implementation.